# How can I show total price at checkout page [OpenCart]

Tags: php, opencart

I would like to make some calculations at the checkout page. If for example the total price of all products is 80€, I want to show a message that says: "You can add more products on cart worth of 20€, so you can get a discount which activates when total cost is 100€".

To do this I have to get the total price as a variable and do this:

```
$tp = totalprice;

if ( $tp < 100 ) {
    $tp_less = 100 - $tp;
}

echo 'You can add more products on cart worth of ' . $tp_less . '€.';
```

The problem here is that I don't know how to get the total price as a variable.

```
<?php echo $cart_total = $this->cart->getTotal(); ?>
```

I placed the above at the file /checkout.tpl but I get an error so it's not working. Actually, whenever I use any code that has 'this' inside it I get error:

"Notice: Undefined property: Template\Basic::$cart"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was:

**At file checkout.php**
    $data['total'] = $this->cart->getTotal();

**At file checkout.tpl**
    echo $total

Comment: `echo 'total = ' $data['total'] = $this->cart->getTotal();` check does it print something?

Answer (score 0):

`$this->cart->getTotal()` - Calculates cart total including taxes

`$this->cart->getSubTotal()` - This calculates products subtotal, I think you need to use this.

`$this->cart->getSubTotal()` - call this function in your controller and store value in a variable and pass it to your tpl file.

**Regarding your error:**

By default cart library is included in opencart, Make sure cart library is included, check registry file

Hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't fully understood the last part about the error. How can i make sure the cart library is included? And what is the registry file. Sorry, I am quite new to OC and don't understand its architecture yet.

Comment: @dominotrix, check this `$registry->set('cart', new Cart($registry));` in your index.php in root folder,